# Use Image in various dynamically loaded Components in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

**What I want to Achive:**
Toggling the appearance of an Item, where the components that describe the appearance are loaded dynamically, but common elements are not loaded multiple times.

Lets say, I have a list of elements with an icon (e.g. cover) and a title (e.g. music title).
When clicked/dragged, it shifts the shape, so additional information can be displayed (e.g. duration, artist, ...).
Finally I have a DropArea, in which I can drop those elements. Here I only want to display the icon.

As I am informed correctly, it is not advisable to have all three forms pre-loaded and only shift the visibility and other parameters of the additional objects, as the first list is a ListView.
Therefore I decided, to create multiple components, and then load them with a Loader.
On the other hand, this leads to some overhead, for I load and unload the Icon, that is common to all the components, each time, the shape shifts.

My solution so far is, to load the image outside of the components, re-parenting it each time, the shape shifts. This however feels odd, and I am not sure, if this might not be the less performing way, compared to the "loading everything at once and resetting visiblity and positioners"-approach

**What is the proper way to do this?**

Answer (score 1):

For the efficiency aspect, the most performing one should be that only dynamically loads something that is really dynamic, and leaves other things static(or so called declarative). In your app, the icon should be declarative, I think.

Regarding with reparenting, actually re-parenting is quite common in Qt Quick programming, especially within dynamically loading context. The parent in Qt Quick is not the same concept of QObject. It's just visual management (not memory management). That's why you can see Qt Quick even provides ParentChange in State/Transition.